# What can I do when "Find My iPhone" won't turn off?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, apple-id, find-my-iphone

I've been trying to restore my iPhone SE (running iOS 10.3.1) from a local iTunes backup, but iTunes on the Mac says that it cannot preform a restore until I turn off the "Find My iPhone" feature. I've been repeatedly trying to do this, but to no avail. I also tried restarting the iPhone or doing a hard reset between attempts.

When I try to turn the Find My iPhone feature off via *Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > Find My iPhone,* the screen shows one of three things:

1. The slider moves to the Off position, but when I return to the
   iCloud page, the Find My iPhone line indicates that the feature is
   still On. (If I return to the Find My iPhone page, it indeed shows the slider
   as On.)
2. A prompt appears, asking for my Apple ID password. Entering it doesn't do anything (obvious).
3. Like # 2, I get an Apple ID prompt. Entering it just leads to an error message: "Verification Failed: There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server." However, when I check [Apple's System Status web page](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/), all of their services (including Apple ID and iCloud) are in the green.

Has anyone else resolved an issue like this? What else can I try? Any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was eventually resolved by turning off the iPhone's Wi-Fi, and then turning off the Find My iPhone feature. (Note: The cellular service was left on.)

Comment: It seems that the issue may have been related to my wi-fi router. Restarting it also helped to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the Settings menu of your device.
Tap the name that you see at the top of the menu.
You should see your available devices and the ability to change personal settings. Tap iCloud.
Scroll down until you see “Find My iPhone” or the green radar icon and tap it.
You can toggle the feature on and off here using the button labeled “Find My iPhone”.

https://www.ubreakifix.com/blog/turn-off-find-iphone